Error: Unable to enable Hubble: release: not found
I have deployed a K8s cluster on minikube via the following command:
minikube start --nodes 2 -p lab --driver=virtualbox --cni=cilium --host-dns-resolver=false --no-vtx-check
After the cluster is created, I can verify that cilium is installed by the cilium daemonset that exists in the kube-system namespace.
When I call cilium status, I get one warning:
Warnings:              cilium             cilium-47x5j    Hubble: Server not initialized

Then when I run cilium hubble enable or cilium hubble enable --ui, I get the following error:
Error: Unable to enable Hubble: release: not found

How to resolve this issue?
I was expecting hubble to be simply enabled after running the cilium hubble enable command as per Cilium's documentations. I spent quite a bit of time researching the error online but I haven't been able to find anything related.

I had the same issue and solved it deploying my minikube cluster with minikube start --network-plugin=cni --cni=false and then starting Cilium using the doc (https://docs.cilium.io/en/stable/gettingstarted/k8s-install-default/) to make it my CNI. After this, enabled Hubble, it went up and could start monitoring the traffic.
